# What is the difference between no parameter and the void parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, parameters, void

I've recently switched from Java to learning C++, I'm a newbie to this language so I need your help :)

What's the difference?

```
void method(void) {

}
```

and

```
void method() {

}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In C++, there's no difference -- they both mean a function that takes zero arguments.

In C, `()` means a function that takes *any number of arguments*, while `(void)` means a function that takes zero arguments.

Comment: Oh right, haha. Thanks for clearing that up! :)

Answer (score 2):

None. There was a difference in C (`void` means no parameters and nothing means an unknown number of parameters) but not in C++; they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

in C++ there is no difference, they are the same

Answer (score 1):

C++ is the exact same, however in C it means a  function that takes any # of arguments. It is really just a stylistic matter that is up to you.